# Dump rows from Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader to a collection that survives closed connection

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net-core, oracle.manageddataaccess

I'm trying to write a simple helper function that connects to Oracle database using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core` library, and returns the rows.

Returned object should survive when connection to database is closed. Something similar to the following. Not sure what the  will be.

```
public <sometype> GetOracleResults(string connectionString, string cmdText, List<OracleParameter> oracleParameters)
{
    <sometype> results = null;
    try
    {
        using (OracleConnection oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            oracleConnection.Open();
            using (OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(cmdText, oracleConnection))
            {
                foreach (var param in oracleParameters)
                {
                    oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
                }
                OracleDataReader oracleDataReader = oracleCommand.ExecuteReader();
                if(oracleDataReader.HasRows)
                {
                    results = new <sometype>();
                    while (oracleDataReader.Read())
                    {
                        //loop through the reader and add results
                        return results;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       //todo
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be strongly typed? If not, a coworker showed me sticking the data in a List of Dictionary items, E.G.:

```
var columns = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < myReader.FieldCount; i++)
{
   columns.Add(myReader.GetName(i).Trim());
}

while (myReader.Read() && results.Count < 200)
{
   Dictionary<string, string> row = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   foreach (var column in columns)
   {
      row.Add(column, Convert.ToString(myReader[column], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Trim());
   }
   results.Add(row);
}
```

I suppose if you know the schema so that the generic type coming into the method had property names matching the column names, then you could use reflection to match up the column results with the C# object.